# Highchartjs won't load

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create two charts using a JSON file

html:

```
<div id="chart-0" class="chart-box"></div>
<div id="chart-1" class="chart-box"></div>
```

js:

```
$(function() {

  Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie'
    },

    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },

    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b> <br>({point.percentage:.1f} %)'
        }
      }
    }

  });


  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/16jm21', function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {

      var options = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'chart-' + key
        },
        title: {
          text: val.name
        },
        series: [{
          name: val.series.name,
          innerSize: '60%',
          data: [val.series.data]
        }]
      }
      console.log(val.series.data)

      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


    });
  });

});
```

json:

```
[{"name":"Projeto 1","series":{"name":"Status","innerSize":"60%","data":[{"name":"Andamento","y":"60","color":"#DDDF00"},{"name":"Concluído","y":"19.2","color":"#3498DB"},{"name":"Atrasado","y":"10.8"},{"name":"Outro","y":"6.5"},{"name":"Outro 2","y":"3.5"}]}},{"name":"Projeto 2","series":{"name":"Status 2","innerSize":"60%","data":[{"name":"Andamento","y":"60","color":"#DDDF00"},{"name":"Concluído","y":"19.2","color":"#3498DB"},{"name":"Atrasado","y":"10.8"},{"name":"Outro","y":"6.5"},{"name":"Outro 2","y":"3.5"}]}}]
```

This json file has data for two charts. Everything seems to work well until I try to push data by passing `val.series.data` into `options.series.data`. The chart load but it is broken, it seems like it's not pushing `val.series.data` properly , it doesn't throw me any errors in console. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it looks like I'm missing something very simple.

Some help would be appreciated.

Here's jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9bor1od3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your example code.

1. When you set the `series.data` you wrap it in an array when it is already an array. Go from:

   ```
   data: [val.series.data]
   ```

   To:

   ```
   data: val.series.data
   ```
2. The `series.data` retrieved by `getJSON` returns strings for the `y` values. You could fix the source to go from:

   ```
   {"name":"Outro","y":"6.5"}
   ```

   To:

   ```
   {"name":"Outro","y": 6.5}
   ```

   Or `parseFloat` the result. A `parseFloat` example:

   ```
   $.each(val.series.data, function(k, v) {
       val.series.data[k].y = parseFloat(val.series.data[k].y);
   });
   ```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/9bor1od3/2/) of the charts showing up.